# Which Facebook API to use for Android project

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, restfb

I want to include a way to search FB posts containing a particular hashtag in my app. I searched the web for FB libraries for android and came across 3:

- facebook-android-sdk : Can never get this thing to download! Also the biggest and bloatiest of all three by size
- facebook4j : Seems similar to twitter4j which I am very familiar with
- restFB : Searching around, I couldn't find for certain whether it supports android or not

Which of these libraries is best suited for me?

Comment: Whichever library you instal, the thing is there's no such API (as of now) that gives you the posts containing a hashtag

Answer (score 0):

facebook-android-sdk is the official sdk provided by FB. [This](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/) is where you can get start